# Memory full Python plotting 3d

Tags: python, memory, printing, matplotlib

I'm getting some memory problems from plotting images in a loop. How do I delete the old ones?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\code stuff\solarsystem.py", line 69, in <module>
    fig = plt.figure()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 79, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 106, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=window)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 225, in __init__
    master=self._tkcanvas, width=w, height=h)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3306, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3262, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer
```

Script:

```
count = 0
xy = bodies[0][2]
x = [[a[0] for a in bodies[0][2]]]
y = [[a[1] for a in bodies[0][2]]]
z = [[a[2] for a in bodies[0][2]]]

for i in range(1,nbodies):
    x.append([a[0] for a in bodies[i][2]])
    y.append([a[1] for a in bodies[i][2]])
    z.append([a[2] for a in bodies[i][2]])

for j in range(0,len(bodies[0][2])-1,10):
    Xc = [[x[0][j]]]
    Yc = [[y[0][j]]]
    Zc = [[z[0][j]]]
    for k in range(1,nbodies):
        Xc.append([x[k][j]])
        Yc.append([y[k][j]])
        Zc.append([z[k][j]])

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    for l in range(len(Xc)):
        ax.scatter( Xc[l], Yc[l], Zc[l], c=(i/nbodies,i/nbodies,i/nbodies))

    ax.axis([-400, 400, -400, 400])
    ax.set_zlim(-400, 400)

    pylab.savefig('images/img'+str(count))
    pylab.clf()
    count += 1

    percent = (j/(len(bodies[0][2])-1.))*100
    if percent % 10 ==0:
        print percent
```

Comment: is this it, or are you generating a number of these figures?

Comment: About 10k atm, want to make more :P

Comment: cool, see my answer below, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're generating a number of pictures, you need to not only call the

```
plt.clf()
```

function between figures, but also the

```
plt.close()
```

function between pictures (i.e. `after the for j in range(0,len(bodies[0][2])-1,10):`
 loop completes)

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the `fig` instance (when you're done with it) using

```
del fig
```

and you can delete the files with `os.unlink`

```
os.unlink('images/img'+str(count))
```

Comment: I need to keep the images till after the loop. Any idea on how to get rid of them after that?